# Is there a sequence producing almost all primes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Is there a sequence which contains only primes and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{p_n} = 1$$ (where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime)?

Edit: sigh. I meant a sequence produced using 0, 1, +, -, *, / used a constant amount of times, powers to a constant and any constant number of the previous elements.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite.  What's wrong with $a_n=p_n$?

Comment: Do we really need to go there? I guess I am looking for a Turing machine then.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific, so as to preclude the trivial solution.

Comment: @chx Do you really want us to produce a Turing machine which outputs precisely the primes? There is one; the property of being prime is decidable.

Comment: With the revised question, I would be curious to know whether even the limit criterion can hold under the given rules of construction.

Comment: The prime gap is bounded so ... why not? http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.308.998&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the trivial solution mentioned in the comments, if you exclude a finite number $k$ of primes, then $a_n=p_{n+k}$ for $n\geq N$ for some $N$ and even in this case you have
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} p_{n+k}/p_n=1$$
(See Cipolla's asymptotic expansion).

If you exclude primes in arithmetic progression, i.e. $a_n=p_{rn}$ for some $n$, then the limit is $r$.

On the other hand I would be surprised if the sequence $a_n$ of all primes but skipping Mersenne's primes doesn't verify what you want. Or all primes skipping twin primes. Or all primes skipping any set of rare primes.

Or if $a_n$ allow repetitions, you can find a lot more examples. For instance any set of primes in where you replace a subset of zero density of primes by the prime "2".

With the additional constraints on $a_n$ you gave, in any case solution $a_n$ to your problem has to match Cipolla's asymptotics, which are precise. I don't see how to do that with the given operations (they generate rational and exponential functions).

Comment: edited the question.

Answer (score -1):

Primes become less common as integers become larger. This includes primes of certain forms, polynomial values and sequences. The Mersenne Numbers $2^n-1$ with $n$ prime have the condition that each divisor of $2^n-1$ must be of the form $8kn+1$ or $8kn-1$, raising the probability of them being prime compared to a random integer $N$ of similar size, however, primes of the form $2^n-1$ are still extremely rare.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t see how this even addresses the OP’s question, let alone answering it.